# how to change the arguments when extending a jQuery function

Tags: jquery

When I modify the arguments of `html()` I get an error that I can't figure out.

In this example I'm just `stringifying` and then `parsing`, and it causes the same error:

```
(function($) {
    var oldhtml = $.fn.html;
    $.fn.html = function() {
        var args = JSON.stringify(arguments);
        // do some stuff with args
        args = JSON.parse(args);
        var ret = oldhtml.apply(this, args);
        return ret;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Getting this error:

> jquery-ui.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: e(...).addClass(...).html(...).appendTo is not a function

Comment: The error seems completely unrelated to the code you've shown. My test case doesn't get that error either: https://jsfiddle.net/06mjdfgu/. Note that it doesn't work because `args` is an object and `arguments` should be an array. I'm not even sure of the point of stringifying/parsing the same data before giving it back to the same function you wrapped.

Comment: yea, u will need to call html() ...

Comment: ... I am? `$('div').html('foo');`

Comment: apologies... still getting this error in my code however... and its a copy :/ get back soon with a better code segment

Comment: Arun P Johny found the answer (below). Not sure why jsfiddle didn't come up with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your use of `JSON.stringify()`, since `arguments` is not a Array object, it will parse it like an key/value object with indexes. So after parsing `args` is no longer an array, instead it is an object.

So a possible solution is convert arguments to an array, then stringify it

```js
(function($) {
  var oldhtml = $.fn.html;
  $.fn.html = function() {

    $('#args-strinfigy').text(JSON.stringify(arguments)); //see this

    var args = JSON.stringify([].slice.call(arguments)); //or JSON.stringify(Array.from(arguments))
    // do some stuff with args
    args = JSON.parse(args);
    var ret = oldhtml.apply(this, args);
    return ret;
  };
})(jQuery);

$('div').html('asdfasd').appendTo('body')
```

```css
div {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<div>
</div>

<pre id="args-strinfigy"></pre>
```

Comment: Well done. completely fixed my problem. why the need for #args-stringify? is it possible to just use a variable?

Comment: @user975033 just to show you what was happening, you can remove it